# WHMCS, how to create template variables from my hook

Tags: whmcs

My question maybe is simple, but anfortunatly I don't know how to answer it.

How can I create a variable in a hook function and then pass a PHP variable from within the function to my Template in order to use it in the form of {VARIABLE_COMES_FROM_HOOK}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in hook categories http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks
There are hooks that return variables to tpl and other that don't do that

Answer (score 4):

WHMCS uses Smarty template engine so as an example inside the **includes/hooks** folder you will have your hook file e.g **hook_example.php** from which you can assign variables to **$smarty** global object and access them in your template as {$VARIABLE_COMES_FROM_HOOK}.

Inside **hook_example.php**:

```
function example() {

    global $smarty;

    $variable = "Hello world!";

    $smarty->assign('VARIABLE_COMES_FROM_HOOK', $variable);

}
```